# Graph in R about profit functions

Tags: r, ggplot2, economics

i have a profit function of informal firms. This informal firm is constrained in capital allocation, i.e, the industry have an limit of capital for informal firms in which this firm cannot pass this limit.
Then, i need to plot their profit function (is a Cob Douglas production function), but this curve needs to change after the firm achieve k limit. I tried to explain a little but i don't sure its work.
that's my current script:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
x <- seq(0, 1, by = .01)
tributo=0.34
alpha=0.3
beta=0.4
w=0.37
r=0.017
kbar=1.9

#iun= informal unconstrained; ic=informal constrained; f= formal
#definindo funções lucro:
Lucrof <- function(x){((1-tributo)^{1/(1-alpha-beta)})* (x^{1/(1-alpha-beta)})*
    (1-alpha-beta)*((beta/w)^{beta/(1-alpha-beta)})*
    ((alpha/r)^{alpha/(1-alpha-beta)})}
lucroiun <- function(x){x^{1/(1-alpha-beta)}*
    (1-alpha-beta)*(beta/w)^{beta/(1-alpha-beta)}*
    (alpha/r)^{alpha/(1-alpha-beta)}}

lucroic <- function(x){(1-beta)*(x^{1/(1-beta)})*((beta^beta*kbar^alpha)
                                             /w^beta)^{1/(1-beta)}-r*kbar}
df <- data.frame(X = x,
                 Y = Lucrof(x))
df2 <- data.frame(X = x,
                  Y = lucroic(x))

#creat a line graph
#first way
plot(x,Lucrof(x), type="l", ylim = c(0,1))+lines(x,lucroic(x)) 

#second way
ggplot(df, aes(X,Y))+ geom_line(size = 1, color = "green")+
  xlab(expression(theta))+ylab(expression(Pi))


ggplot(df2, aes(X,Y))+ geom_line(size = 1, color = "red")+
         xlab(expression(theta))+ylab(expression(Pi))

#unir os gráficos:
ggplot(df, aes(X,Y))+ geom_line(size = 1)+ylim(0,1)+ 
  geom_line(df2, mapping = aes(X,Y),size = 1, color = "red")+
  geom_line(aes(x,lucroiun(x)), size = 1, color = "red", linetype = 2)+
  labs(x = expression(theta), y = expression(Pi),
       title = "Profit functions", 
       subtitle = "Profit for formal and informal according to managerial abilities")+
  theme_classic()
```

The problem here is that this two functions, lucroiun and lucroic, must be the same curve. in the first moment, the informal agent profit function must be "lucrounc" , and after the agent rech the limit kbar the informal agent become constraint and consequently their profit function becomes "lucroic". unfortunately i couldn't figure out better ways to do that.
Please help-me.

I try to correct my graph in R to use in my paper.

Comment: What exactly does `tributo` refer to?  Without it, we can't reproduce your code. Thank you!

Comment: "lucroiun and lucroic, must be the same curve (...) after the unconstrained informal achieves k limit". What is this "k limit"? And how should it make both functions yield the same result? This seems more of a theory question, perhaps something wrong in how you defined your functions

Comment: I sorry, i made a little mistake. Already corrected and tributo is now defined. Can you help-me now?

Comment: Hi Ricardo. in truth, there is just two functions that i want to plot: Lucrof and lucroinf (which this second one should be lucroiun and lucroic after some point). lucroinf is a profit function of a specific firm. And this firm can allocate two factors, given other parameters, to maximize their profit function. The factor k, which this firm will choose have an allocation limit, when the function "lucroiun" achieves this limit, they cant increase k even as x grows. The issue here is because i first solve the problem manually and added in R with everything in function of exogenous parameters.

Comment: My goal is almost identical to the first graph on this paper: THE INFORMAL SECTOR: AN EQUILIBRIUM MODEL AND SOME EMPIRICAL EVIDENCE FROM BRAZIL.